# How to start and stop animation in avalonia

Tags: animation, avalonia

In Avalonia, how to start and stop in keyframe animations

```
private Animation StartAnimation(Control control)
        {
            Animation animation = new Animation();
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            animation.IterationCount = new IterationCount(2);

            KeyFrame key1 = new KeyFrame();
            key1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(WidthProperty, 50 + 10d));
            key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(HeightProperty, 50 + 10d));
            key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(OpacityProperty, 1));
            animation.Children.Add(key1);
            return animation;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response..

> In Avalonia, how to start and stop in keyframe animations

Assuming you're only interested in keyframes, since you can mix the code-behind with XAML-Markup, I can think of two ways,.. Here is a full example for your example code, I commented some changes/errors, so you can still copy paste it.

**A) Code behind**

```
public class FooControl : TemplatedControl
{
    // assuming you derived from a TemplatedControl since you used 
    // WidthProperty etc.
    
    private FooControl @this = null;
    private CancellationToken _cancelToken;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource;
    private Clock _animationClock = null;    
    private Animation _animation = null;
    
    public FooControl()
    {
        @this = this;   // for Async calls with 'this' as parameter
    
        _animationClock = new Clock();
        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _cancelToken= _cancelTokenSource.Token;
        _animation = CreateAnimation();
    }
    
    // I changed your 'StartAnimation(..)' to 'CreateAnimation()'
    // Also you didn't use/need the parameter 'control' 
    // !!!
    // Important: You always need at least two Keyframes!
    // The animation-system tries to interpolate between the source- 
    // and destination-values of a setter-property of two adjacent 
    // keyframes
    
    private Animation CreateAnimation()
    {
        _animation = new Animation();
        _animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        _animation.IterationCount = new IterationCount(2);
        
        KeyFrame key0 = new KeyFrame();
        key0.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
        key0.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(WidthProperty, 0));
        key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(HeightProperty, 0));
        key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(OpacityProperty, 0));
        
        KeyFrame key1 = new KeyFrame();
        key1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(WidthProperty,50+10));
        key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(HeightProperty,60));
        key1.Setters.Add(new Avalonia.Styling.Setter(OpacityProperty,1));
        _animation.Children.Add(key1);
        
        return animation;
    }
    

    private async Task RunAnimation()
    {
        await _scrollingAnimation?.RunAsync(_scrollingStackPanel,_playbackClock);
    }

    private void StopAnimation() 
    {
        _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

For cancellation Tokens refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0)

**B) using XAML/Markup**

Add the animation to a Style in XAML and give that style a selector. With
which use can activate/deactivate styles and animations. Common is using a
custom Pseudoclass. By adding or removing the currently set
Pseudoclass you then would also trigger/cancel the animation.

Method to set/remove pseudoclasses (static call):

> Pseudoclasses.Set(":pseudoclassname", bool isSet);

This Can be mixed with code behind.
I Can add a full example source for a XAML-Version if someone asks for it.